# Sql database cicd using github actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions, continuous-deployment

We are using Azure Devops as CICD tool for database deployment. We are using DACPAC and bitbucket as a source control. Soon we are migrating to Github and we will be using github actions for cicd. Is someone used github actions to deploy sql database changes? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: There are some actions that could help, specifically with AZURE. You can check what is available on the Github Action marketplace here: https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=sql

Comment: Thank you. Will have look on this.